# Marginal Cost and lagrange multiplier

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

I'm studying basic micro, and I did not get how such a result is possible.

According to what I studied, the marginal cost is simply the partial derivative of the cost function with respect to the output $y$. If the cost function is linear, and it is simply equal to $ C(W,R,y) = W l^\star +R k^\star$, where $l^\star$ and $k^\star$ are the conditional demand functions (depending on $y$ as well), why the MC is not linear?
What I have done is to solve the cost minimization problem and to take the ratio of the optimal solutions, and then solving for one of the two input factors. After that, I substituted into the production function and solving for the other input factor, I find the conditional demand function of one input and then I find the conditional demand function of the other one. In the end I simply subsituted into the cost function and derived with respect to $y$.  However this does not give me the result below in red.

[image]

[image]

Can you show me how to get the result in red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the cost function is linear, and it is simply equal to (,,)=⋆+⋆, where ⋆ and ⋆ are the conditional demand functions (depending on  as well), why the MC is not linear?

The cost function is linear in $l$ and in $k$, but it need not be linear in $y$, that is,  $l(y, *)$ and $k(y, *)$ are not, in general, linear functions of $y$.
The marginal cost is the derivative of $C(W, R, y )$ with respect to $y$, not with respect to $l$ or $k$.

Remember that when calculating the marginal cost you use the chain rule, which involves the derivatives of $l$ and $k$ with respect to $y$.

Formally:

$MC= \frac{\partial (,,) }{\partial y}= W \frac{\partial  l(y, *)}{\partial y}+R \frac{\partial k(y,*)}{\partial y}$

As for the equation in red, you can proceed as follows:

[image]